# Showing a bijection between the set of ringhomomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[i] \to R$ and the set of $x \in R$ for which $x^2+1=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying basic ring theory and I am stuck on the following (possibly easy) **question**.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Prove that there is a bijection between the set of ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[i]\to R$ and the set of $x\in R$ for which $x^2+1=0$.

Some  things I **remember** and can prove:

If $f$ is a ring homomorphism then $f(1)=1, f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. Also $\mathbb{Z}[i]^* =\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ and I can prove $\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1)$. My idea would be to construct a map from the set of ring homomorphisms to the set of $x \in R$ for which $x^2+1=0$ and show that it's bijective. The problem is that I don't know how to construct such a map (what does the set of ring homomorphisms look like?) and where to use that $R$ is commutative.

Any answer/big hint would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Brings to mind a possible category theory extension of the problem: prove that the bijection is an isomorphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}_{Rings}(\mathbb{Z}[i], \cdot) \simeq \{ x \in \cdot : x^2 + 1 = 0 \}$ and therefore the right-hand functor is representable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given if $x\in R$ and the equation $x^2+1=0$ holds, then the ring homomorphism $f$ determined by $X\mapsto x$ from $\mathbb Z[X]\to R$ contains $(X^2+1)$ in its kernel. By the [fundamental theorem of homomorphsisms for rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms), there exists $g$ from $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)\to R$ such that $g\pi=f$ where $\pi:\mathbb Z[X]\to \mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)$ is the canonical projection. Since this latter ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[i]$, we have found the map, call it $g_x$, corresponding to $x\in R$.

Now given a homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z[i]\to R$, $f(i)$ satisfies the equation $x^2+1=0$ because $f(i)^2+1=f(i^2+1)=f(0)=0$. So to each homomorphism $f$ like this, we can associate $f(i)$. Now we have a rule that maps function to elements of $R$.

I'll leave it to you to demonstrate they are mutually inverse.